# How to change SQL_MODE and FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS after connection using PHP and MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHP with OO MySQLi. The connection has already been opened but now I need to disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS and set SQL_MODE. Then I need to renable the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS after a series of scripts.

If I did it all in MySQL, it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('foreign', 'key', 'violation'); -- prevented

SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('foreign', 'key', 'violation'); -- allowed
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('foreign', 'key', 'violation'); -- prevented
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run each statement separately with mysqli_query().

The sql_mode and foreign_key_checks settings are session-based, so they stay in effect until you change them back, or else end the session.